# How to properly use Ftpasswd to make a user?

Tags: ftp

I wanna make an FTP user with my proFTPd server and I want the user to be restricted to one directory. How would I do this? Im using this to try and make a user but its just giiving me an Authentication Failed error when trying to connect:

```
ftpasswd --passwd --file=/ftpd.passwd --name=ftpu1 --uid=1031 --home=/opt/lampp/htdocs/ --shell=/bin/false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does [proftpd debug logging](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Debugging.html) show, when you attempt to login with the user you created with `ftpasswd`?  Is your `proftpd` configured to use that `/ftpd.passwd` file via "AuthUserFile /ftpd.passwd`" in the `proftpd.conf`?